# flutter doctor --android-licenses not working on macOS Catalina

Tags: android, flutter, macos-catalina, android-sdk-manager

Recently I upgraded my Mac to Catalina.

I installed Java, set **`JAVA_HOME`** to `$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` as per the documentation. I installed Android Studio and SDK tools and set the **`ANDROID_HOME`** variable to `/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk`.

I downloaded flutter, and added `flutter/bin` to my env variable **`$PATH`**, and when I run **`flutter doctor`**, it's running fine and giving me the results as expected, without all the features checked however as I am setting it up for the first time.

But when I run **`flutter doctor --android-licenses`**, it's giving me an error which says:

> Android sdkmanager tool was not found, try re-installing or upgrading your Android SDK.

Comment: I was able to get one step further by installing the cmdline-tools from android studio sdk manager and copying the contents of sdk/cmdline-tools/latest to sdk/tools directory. But even after that when I run the command it says "A newer version of Android SDK is required". When I run the mentioned command "./sdkmanager --update" it says "JDK command not found".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the command **`flutter upgrade`**.

Then run the command **`flutter doctor --android-licenses`**.

Actually it was the then latest version of **Flutter** `1.12.13+hotfix.8` installed, which was not reading the **`cmdline-tools`** folder from the latest `Android SDK home`.

Also to be on the safer side, just create a folder **`tools`** inside `<path-to-sdk-home>`, and copy the contents of `<path-to-sdk-home>/cmdline-tools/latest/` to the folder `<path-to-sdk-home>/tools/`.